# How to interface null-terminated string with VB.NET program?

Tags: vb.net, dll

I have a VB.NET program that uses FTDI library FTD2XX.
There is a library function returning null-terminated strings in buffers passed as pointers:

```c
FT_STATUS FT_GetDeviceInfoDetail (DWORD dwIndex, LPDWORD lpdwFlags, 
    LPDWORD lpdwType, LPDWORD lpdwID, LPDWORD lpdwLocId, 
    PCHAR pcSerialNumber, PCHAR pcDescription, FT_HANDLE *ftHandle)
```

I tried this declaration in VB.NET:

```
Private Declare Function 
   FT_GetDeviceInfoDetail Lib "FTD2XX.DLL" (
      ByVal ftIndex As Integer, ByRef ftFlags As Long, ByRef ftType As Long,
      ByRef ftDevId As Long, ByRef ftDevLocation As Long, 
      ByRef ftSerialNumber As String, ByRef ftDevDescription As String, 
      ByRef ftHandle As Integer) As Integer
```

Because some internet resource suggested that VB.NET marshalling will take care of the end nulls and conversion between LPSTRING a C-style string.
Well, it is not true, at least when FTDI library function declares PCHAR (which is FTDI's special way to say it's simply `char *`).
When used with this declaration, calling the function raises exception:

System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'

What would be the right way to allocate a buffer and interface my VB.NET program correctly with the FTDI driver function?

Comment: Can you add the VB6 prototype (Declare) for that method to your question? You might want to look into [String marshaling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-for-strings). You might also want to have a look at [PInvoke.net](https://pinvoke.net/) for samples.

Comment: You shouldn't use that form to declare a Function, use the `<DllImport>` version. Also, specify the `CallingConvention` (e.g., `CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl`). Then you can simply use a string (remove `ByRef`). -- `UnmanagedType.LPStr` is the default for Platform Invoke.

Comment: But, it could be `CallingConvention.StdCall`. You should know that. Also declare the charset explicitly, e.g., `CharSet = CharSet.Ansi`

Comment: Thank you, @Jimi, for the pointer. My projects are normally either all SQL or typescript/javascript. In this case, the customer insists on Visual Basic for good reasons (building on some code that already exists, plus possibility to do minor changes themselves), I am just helping them create basic app and then take over early, so I also learn on the run :)

Comment: I am looking for docs but cannot find any relevant examples for vb.net :(

Comment: [DllImport](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute) -- The language selector is in the upper band of the MSDN pages.

Comment: I am afraid I cannot see any useful information for interfacing between the DLL and VB.NET. Weher could I find any docs that would specify how to map different VB.NET types to unmanaged DLL. It's a list of items but no explanation how it actually works and I can't see any reference list. Just one example, which does not help.

Comment: [Conventions for Function Prototypes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/conventions-for-function-prototypes) -- [Windows Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types) -- [Default Marshaling Behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-behavior) -- [Default marshaling for strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-for-strings) -- [Marshaling Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-strings)

Comment: @Jimi, thank you, I read all this C# docs before. There is no hint, not a single example, how to declare/import, for instance, pointer to DWORD in VB.NET. My guess is ByRef X as UInt16, but I cannot find any confirmation  in the VB.NET docs (C# is fine, but it does not help me in VB.NET). Same for the strings where the library function expects to receive an allocated LPCSTR buffer - no example, no spec for VB.NET. All the docs are written for people who "should know" or already know and don't need the docs. Catch 22. Hopelessly useless for anything else except very primitive examples.